iOS disable TextField's AutoFill feature
I want to disable autofill feature from textfield's action. I added image.
Autofill is coming directly. Event I try to disable Paste action with like this, I can disable Paste action, it works but Autofill still shown.
    override func canPerformAction(_ action: Selector, withSender sender: Any?) -> Bool {
    if action == #selector(UIResponderStandardEditActions.paste(_:)) {
        return false
    }
    return super.canPerformAction(action, withSender: sender)
}

How can I disable "AutoFill" feature from textfield?


Here’s how you can disable AutoFill for a UITextField:
let textField = UITextField()
textField.textContentType = .none

Disabling AutoFill in Interface Builder

Select your UITextField in Interface Builder.
In the Identity Inspector, locate the Text Content Type field.
Set it to None.


You can use TextField's shouldChangeCharactersIn function. Here is the code example:
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let numericSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: numericSet.inverted) {
        // If the condition true that means string includes non-numeric character(s). So need to return false
        return false
    }
    
    return true
}

This function prevents non-numeric characters from being entered into the text field.

I already have this function for check string but it doesn't work, it directly set textfield's text.

Can you share code snippet of your textfield's function here ? might be something wrong there. Also don't forget to set "textField.delegate = self" in your viewController

I set delegate, I can handle delegate function, but this doesn't work.

You can handle this with two way, first way disable autofill.
You have to subclass UITextField and put this code block inside this class.
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
    override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
        if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            builder.remove(menu: .autoFill)
        }
        super.buildMenu(with: builder)
    }

Second way, handle after editing.
///Add target to textField :
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleEditing(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


After shouldChangeCharactersIn enters this function:
@objc private func handleEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
             //TODO: Things you want to handle
            }

Important Note: autoFill bypass shouldChangeCharactersIn function, you have to handle it after shouldChangeCharactersIn.

How can you handle autofill by using the .editingChanged event? That event will be called for far more things than just autofill.

Because .editingChanged works right after autoFill, you can quickly edit your textField. If there are unwanted changes, you can undo them.
